# Remove inactive search service topology from a Sharepoint Server 13

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, topology, searchserviceapplication

I have been trying to remove an inactive clone topology, that was created by executing

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $ssa -SearchTopology $current
```

by executing

```
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity <guid>
```

and the outcome is the below image

[image]

Basically, what i was trying to achieve was to move the index component to another partition than Local Disk.

Has anyone faced any similar problems?

I am able to add a new inactive topology but i am not licensed to remove it?

It's an Sharepoint Server 13 On-Prem installment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as it turns out, i was under the belief that the sharepoint server was at least Sharepoint Server 13- Standard edition.

Unfortunately, it was Sharepoint Foundation 13, which cannot allow you to perform such actions.

There is [a detailed post here](https://www.jasjitchopra.com/provision-search-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-using-powershell-with-clean-db-names/), which describes the procedure followed in order to setup the SSA, but i still haven't tried out if some of the scripts might have worked in my case.